# Why does useLazyLoadQuery() appear to be like blocking and can cause a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, react-suspense, react-relay

I am following the tutorial of Relay and it is Step 3, as on https://relay.dev/docs/tutorial/queries-1/. The code with my debugging, is

```
export default function Newsfeed() {
  console.log("HERE 0")

  const data = useLazyLoadQuery(
    NewsfeedQuery,
    {}
  )

  console.log("HERE 1", JSON.stringify(data));
```

and in the Google Chrome's dev console, I am able to see the following:

[image]

So it is very strange: it looks like it is able to reach the "HERE 0", and then fetch data, **as if it is blocking I/O (network fetch) (the term blocking I/O means, like in the old days, when we do a Unix system call `read()`, this function will never return until it has finished the reading task, unlike nowadays, we do a JavaScript `fetch()` and set up a `then` handler and `fetch()` immediately returns without reading a single byte from the network)**, and then cause a re-render of the component again: note that it didn't go to "HERE 1", but did a "HERE 0" again, and then "HERE 1".

This is very different from what React works like. Traditional React app is like,

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => { 
  // fetching data here
}, []);

return (
  <div>{
     data && ... // display the data
  }</div>
);
```

that is, it will go to the end of function and does not show anything, because `data` is null. Once `data` is something caused by the `setData`, which causes a re-render, then the component will show something.  So it is a running to the completion of the function TWICE.

The `useLazyLoadQuery()` code above does not look like a "run to completion TWICE". It looks like it magically can cause a re-render in the middle.

In fact it doesn't look like it is "lazy". It looks like it is diligently working (how the blocking I/O was in the old days).

How does it work?

Comment: This could be due to reacts `StrictMode` (https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) which renders hooks twice in development to prevent some common bugs

Comment: I didn't find any `StrictMode` in the index file, but I just searched for "Strict" for all the folders and found `const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,` in next.config.js, so I changed it to false and restarted the server, and the results are the same as in the original question

Comment: besides, if it is due to StrictMode, should it output "HERE 0" "HERE 1" twice, but not "HERE 0" "HERE 0" and then  "HERE 1"

Comment: fiar point, is is possible to reproduce your issue in a code-sandbox (or similar tool) so we can have a more in-depth look

Comment: @Xiduzo I was wondering about that too, but since GraphQL and Relay was running as a server too, I think codesandbox may not be able to run it, and you may need to do the `git clone` step as in the tutorial and run it locally. It is really simple though.

Comment: I ran it locally and added an answer to what is happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Relay uses Suspense. From tutorial you linked:

> Relay uses Suspense to show a loading indicator until the data is available.

When using Suspense for data fetch (either throwing promises or using new `use` hook), React will stop rendering ('suspend') component if it requires some data which isn't here yet. React will show `fallback` of nearest Suspense boundary and re-render subtree when data is loaded.

In your case `useLazyLoadQuery` requests some data under the hood and Next.js handles all Suspense-related stuff, so this might be less noticeable. But if you'd try to use `useLazyLoadQuery` in plain React project (i.e. without frameworks), you probably will get error from React as it was unable to find Suspense boundary, unless you explicitly define one.

I did a bit of digging about all things Suspense and wrote an [article](https://sinja.io/blog/guide-to-react-suspense) some time ago. If you're interested in how Suspense works it might be good starting point.

Comment: that's good to know. Sometimes with React, for me or my coworkers, it is like we "do this" or "do that" and nobody really understands what happens. If it is SICP's "abstraction" or black box, it is ok to say it works and the interface is this and this, and that's it -- you don't need to understand how it is implemented. But I think with web programming, there are all the network traffic and events, and we needing to add code into it, so it is more difficult to think of it as a black box

Comment: Is this explained in your post I wonder? how does a suspense "stop" the code from running after `useLazyLoadQuery()`? (that is, the first console.log() ran, and then the useLazyLoadQuery(), and then what is stopping the second console.log() from running?) It is not by injecting some electrons into the processor to alter it, right? And the component is not an async function. If it were, then at least I understand it as "it is really like an await, meaning a promise to be resolved and will run the "thenable" code (the "then" handler)

Comment: I don't cover exact implementation details in my post, but there are two ways to initiate 'suspension': by `throw`ing promise (with slight modifications) directly or by passing promise to `use` hook (which also does `throw` under the hood). In both cases your component (or rather hook you called) throws something, which in turn interrupts code flow and 'bubbles up' until it reaches try-catch block. This try-catch block is located in reconciler (part of React which does executes your function components and compares returned JSX to what we have in vdom) and when it catches...

Comment: ...promise/exception from `use` hook it responds accordingly by stopping current render, finding nearest <Suspense> boundary, suspending its children and showing fallback. If you wrap call to `useLazyLoadQuery` in try-catch you should be able to see what it throws

Comment: my goodness... `throw` in order to stop... it is like back in the old days in the '80s, machine code programs use an interrupt instruction to do something... not sure if it is still being used today

Answer (score 1):

Digging a bit deeper into the [relay documentation](https://relay.dev/docs/next/guided-tour/rendering/loading-states/) which states:

*To render loading states while a query is being fetched, we rely on React Suspense. Suspense is a new feature in React that allows components to interrupt or "suspend" rendering in order to wait for some asynchronous resource (such as code, images or data) to be loaded; when a component "suspends", it indicates to React that the component isn't "ready" to be rendered yet, and won't be until the asynchronous resource it's waiting for is loaded. When the resource finally loads, React will try to render the component again.*

Looking at the repo from the tutorial you are following I can see the app is wrapped in a `<React.Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>`

This means all code below your `useLazyLoadQuery` won't be executed until it is giving the signal the component is *ready*.

All code above will get executed which is why you are seeing `"HERE 0"` twice.

The rendering process will be as follows

1. Render the `Newsfeed` component (from `App.tsx`)
2. `console.log("HERE 0");`
3. `React.Suspense` until `useLazyLoadQuery` is ready, and *suspense* all other code in the `Newsfeed` component
4. when `useLazyLoadQuery` has data it will trigger to re-render the `Newsfeed` component
5. Re-render the `Newsfeed` component
6. `console.log("HERE 0");`
7. `React.Suspense` does not kick in because `useLazyLoadQuery` has data
8. `console.log("HERE 1", JSON.stringify(data));`
9. ... rest of the `Newsfeed` component

Comment: how does a suspense "stop" the code from running after `useLazyLoadQuery()`? (that is, the first console.log() ran, and then the useLazyLoadQuery(), and then what is stopping the second console.log() from running?)  It is not by injecting some electrons into the processor to alter it, right? And the component is not an async function. If it were, then at least I understand it as "it is really like an await, meaning a promise to be resolved and will run the "thenable" code (the "then" handler)

Comment: I think this article is quite clear on what is happening https://blog.logrocket.com/data-fetching-react-suspense/#:~:text=Suspense%20is%20a%20feature%20for,to%20manage%20state%20like%20Redux.

react-relay must have built-in something similar in their `useLazyLoadQuery` hook

Comment: A small example I made using the code from the blog can be found at `https://codesandbox.io/s/react-suspense-example-lmjjqf` which has a poor-mans implementation of `useLazyLoadQuery`